# Track calls to auto implemented properties

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, aop

Is there a way that I can track and intercept calls to values in properties that are auto implemented?

I'd like to have code that looks a bit like this:

```
[Tracked]
public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Ideally the attribute would be able to intercept changes to the property values. Is this possible?

What I don't want it to have a second piece of code spin over an object later and request the values, but rather the attribute should tack the value as it is being set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The way you do this is by not using auto properties. The only possible solution there is, is to use something like [Castle AOP](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) to create automatic wrappers around your class and have that track the changes, but this is a lot of difficult work to implement.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with an AOP framework, such as [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) (which I note is now commercial). There are a few more linked [here](http://www.bodden.de/tools/aop-dot-net/), but some of the links are dead.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solution that works at runtime, then you'll want an aspect-oriented programming (AOP) framework; I've used [CciSharp](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp) with some success. It's not as mature as PostSharp, but works on the same basic principle: it will modify your already-compiled code, producing another assembly.

If you are just wanting this for testing (or profiling), then there is another option: [Microsoft Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) (which is also free). It works very differently; it uses a "detour" type of injection to change the program while it's running, intercepting the property getter and setter methods.